# Configuring JRE in AIX without installp

Tags: java, aix

Is it possible to configure JRE in AIX without using **installp**.
By simply downloading the archive file which contains a complete java directory (like in windows).
And later on, setting environment variables like JAVA_HOME in os (if required).

If **yes** then please provide me link where I get that archive of jre.

If **no** then please suggest me to install jre in AIX without overwriting the previous version of java (which is already install in machine)
and environment variables related to installed java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only provider of JDK/JRE for AIX is IBM. And as far as I know the only format they provide is in package (to be installed with `installp`). And AFAIK you can't install it on different place. Moreover this installation will update probably your current installation. And of course will keep all your settings

Comment: Note: different major versions can be installed paralelly, they will be placed into directories like `/usr/javaN` or `/usr/javaN_64` (where N can be 14, 5, 6, 71, 8).